# django translation is not working when using sublanguages

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

I have a list of languages for my django project and they work perfectly:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('es', ugettext('Spanish')),
)
```

Now I want to add English UK because some users wrote me about spelling errors that aren't really errors, just the difference between both UK and US english, so I added:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    #('en-us', ugettext('English US')),
    ('es', ugettext('Spanish')),
    ('en-gb', ugettext('English UK')),
)
```

and did all the process to create the language files, but when I select the 'en-gb' it just uses the same files as 'en'. Notice that I try using both 'en' and a new 'en-us'

I tried to add 'fr' to the list and use the translation files I have for 'en-gb' and they work perfectly.

How can I make the 'en-gb' work? I could just use a language code that I'm probably never going to use and put my files there, but that does not seem the right way to do it and I'm probably just missing something simple to make the 'en-gb' work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `en_GB`, not `en-gb`. [See the docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/conf/locale).

Comment: Thanks, that does work. I was using en-gb becuase thats how they put the language codes on the examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/
near the end on the "How Django discovers language preference" section

Comment: That section isn't written very well, esp. since Django has a strong preference for `_` over `-`.